# mongodb match an item in an array as part of aggregation pipeline

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to match a record if one value is in an array of the document
OR other criteria are met. I don't get an error, but I get no records returned.

Any help appreciated (I have looked at other posts regarding arrays and aggregation - I could not get them to work either - so this is probably a duplicate, sorry)

Data:

```
_id:5c93f908aa338366bd00b966
name:"Davidson"
type:["G"]


_id:5c93f908aa338366bd00b977
name:"Robertson"
type:["G","R"]
```

Query:

```
thing.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        $or: [
            {
                "name": { 
                    $regex: "xx", 
                    $options: "i" 
                }
            },
            { 
                "type": {
                    $elemMatch: {
                        "type": "G"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]            
    }   
}])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `$elemMatch`:

```
db.col.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        $or: [
            {
                "name": { 
                    $regex: "xx", 
                    $options: "i" 
                }
            },
            { 
                "type": "G"
            }
        ]            
    }   
}])
```

it checks if `type` array contains any `"G"`